# Logs components hierarchies at a given positon

Tags: codenameone

For debugging purposes, I would like to know which hierarchy (or hierarchies) of Components are placed in a given position of the screen, knowing the absolute X and Y.

I also would like to know which of these components responds to the tap of the screen.

The app has a form inside a form and the inner form has several layered pane layers. There are also tabs. A lot of Components are added and removed in the same Form during the app execution. The layout is so complex that the use of the Component Inspector is not trivial, that's why I would like to use a method to log directly what it is placed in a given position.

I image a such method added to the action listener of a full screen  transparent component, for debugging added to a layered pane on the top of all other layers.

Thank you for any advice.

*(Do you think that a similar functionality can be added in some way to the Simulator?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
Component cmp = parentForm.getComponentAt(x, y);
```

That's the clickable component. To get the hierarchy use `cmp.getParent()` recursively to get the full path.

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the right hint. I elaborated you answer adding another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I elaborated the [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616050/2670744) to get an implementation of what I asked. I share what I've done hoping that it can be useful. My code has side effects and issues, but for a temporary test to discover what is placed in a given position is enough.

Example of log produced by the following code, clicking on a text:

```
[EDT] 0:2:53,552 - You CLICKED on:
-> TextArea[x=4 y=14 width=215 height=96 name=null]
Hierarchy:
-> SpanLabel[x=0 y=0 width=219 height=124 name=null, layout = BorderLayout, scrollableX = false, scrollableY = false, components = [Label, TextArea]]
-> Container[x=0 y=92 width=219 height=124 name=null, layout = BoxLayout, scrollableX = false, scrollableY = false, components = [SpanLabel]]
-> Container[x=3 y=3 width=219 height=308 name=null, layout = BorderLayout, scrollableX = false, scrollableY = false, components = [Container]]
etc.
```

I call the `addLogForClicks()` in the constructor of a class that extends `Form`, only when the app is running on the Simulator. Code:

```
private void addLogForClicks() {
        Container layer = this.getLayeredPane(BaseForm.class, 99);
        layer.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
        Button btn = new Button("", "NoMarginNoPadding");
        btn.addPointerPressedListener(l -> {
            Component cmp = this.getContentPane().getComponentAt(l.getX(), l.getY());
            Log.p("You CLICKED on:\n-> " + cmp + "\nHierarchy:\n" + getHierarchy(cmp), Log.DEBUG);
            if (cmp.respondsToPointerEvents()) {
                cmp.pointerPressed(l.getX(), l.getY());
            }
            if (cmp instanceof Container && ((Container) cmp).getLeadParent() != null && ((Container) cmp).getLeadParent().getLeadComponent() != null) {
                ((Container) cmp).getLeadParent().getLeadComponent().pointerPressed(l.getX(), l.getY());
            }
        });
        btn.addPointerReleasedListener(l -> {
            Component cmp = this.getContentPane().getComponentAt(l.getX(), l.getY());
            if (cmp.respondsToPointerEvents()) {
                cmp.pointerReleased(l.getX(), l.getY());
            }
            if (cmp instanceof Container && ((Container) cmp).getLeadParent() != null && ((Container) cmp).getLeadParent().getLeadComponent() != null) {
                ((Container) cmp).getLeadParent().getLeadComponent().pointerReleased(l.getX(), l.getY());
            }
        });
        layer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, btn);

    }

    private String getHierarchy(Component cmp) {
        String result = "";
        if (cmp.getParent() != null && !(cmp.getParent() instanceof Form)) {
            result = "-> " + cmp.getParent() + "\n" + getHierarchy(cmp.getParent());
        }
        return result;
    }
```